# How to post time using bootstrap datetimepicker from view to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker for date time functionality. While I am trying to post only 'Time' to controller from view the time is coming as '00:00:00' and not the actual selected the time is coming.

Below is my code
Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtStartTime",@name= "StartTime" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtEndTime", @name = "EndTime" })
```

Code written in `document.Ready` function to show only 'Time' from datetimepicker

```
$('#txtStartTime').datetimepicker({ format: 'LT A' });
$('#txtEndTime').datetimepicker({ format: 'LT A' });
```

However, on form submit I am getting the value as '00:00:00' only, attached is the screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacuse you are using the wrong format

```
$('#txtStartTime').datetimepicker({ format: 'hh:mm:ss'  });
$('#txtEndTime').datetimepicker({ format: 'hh:mm:ss'  });
```

If you want to use your format make StartTime and EndDate strings in your model and then parse them in Controller.

Comment: That's Correct ! by adding this format its working, but I want show AM/PM while selecting time. So if I add format as `format: hh:mm A` then its not working. So how can I do this with AM/PM ?

Comment: you can make StartTime  and EndTime  strings and in controller
TimeSpan.TryParse()
and show error if format is wrong

Comment: @Ahemd Ragheb Means I didn't get you ? Why I need to parse the timespan and show it to the user if AM/PM selection is available within datetimepicker ?

Comment: @Rohit beacuse TimeSpan need this formt (hh:mm:ss) .. so usually to mek things easy to myself .. i took variables as strings and parse it

Comment: Ok So how can make datetimepicker to show 24 hrs time instead of 12 hrs, so the user can understand by looking the time itself ?

Comment: If these answer your question, solved your problem and you satisifed with answer, could you mark it as solved to help other who search

Comment: Thanks for solution !